# Where is the left margin width configured in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, gutter

I recently started having HUGE left margins in PyCharm, but cannot find where this is configured.  I've searched Google and the help topics for "margin", but everything seems focused on the right margin.  This makes me think it's something with a similar effect but different name.

[image: screenshot of editor]

Comment: Have you checked the code indentation setting? Did this change?